# line -1, column -1: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch() from the type Database Stack Trace: null

Tags: apex, batch, class

I keep getting this error for every Apex Test when trying to move this Apex Class to production. It is an updated version to an old class that I did not make. I could not write this myself but I only changed very little things and it runs fine in Sandbox when using execute anonymous.

> line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class ForgotPasswordController : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch(DailyTaskOwnerBatchUpdate) from the type Database
> Stack Trace: null"

```java
public class DailyTaskOwnerBatchUpdate implements Schedulable{ 
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        //Creating map to store user names and minimize SOQL queries.
        Map<ID,User> ownerMap = new Map<ID,User>();
        
        //Pulling list of Contacts with updated owners and the associated owner ID.
        for (List<Contact> cList : [SELECT ID, ownerid, contact_owner_updated__c FROM Contact WHERE contact_owner_updated__c = true]){
            
            //Making map of contacts for easy owner reference later.
            Map<ID,Contact> cMap = new Map<ID,Contact>();
            cMap.putAll(cList);
            
            //Building a set of owner IDs to query owner names to include in comments.
            Set<ID> tempOSet = new Set<ID>();
            for (Contact c : cList){
                tempOSet.add(c.ownerid);
            }
            
            //Pulling OPEN tasks assigned to Contacts.
             for (List<Task> tList : [SELECT ID, whoid, ownerid, description, Owner_is_Recruiter__c FROM Task WHERE whoid IN :cList AND Status = 'Not Started' AND Owner_is_Recruiter__c = TRUE]) {
                
                //Adding to set of owner IDs to import owner names.
                for (Task t : tList) {
                    tempOset.add(t.ownerid);
                }
                
                //Getting owner names if there are new owners available.
                if ( !ownerMap.keyset().containsall(tempOSet) ) {
                    ownerMap.putall( [SELECT ID, Name FROM User WHERE ID IN :tempOSet] );
                }
                
                
                List<Task> updatedTasks = new List<Task>();
                
                //Updating Task owner value and description.
                for (Task t : tList) {
                    if ( t.ownerid != cMap.get(t.whoid).ownerid ) {
                        if ( t.description == null) {
                            t.description = '***Task owner updated from ' + ownerMap.get(t.ownerid).Name + ' to ' + ownerMap.get(cMap.get(t.whoid).ownerid).Name + ' on ' + System.now().format('M/d/yyyy K:mm:ss a','America/Chicago') + '.';
                        } else {
                            t.description = '***Task owner updated from ' + ownerMap.get(t.ownerid).Name + ' to ' + ownerMap.get(cMap.get(t.whoid).ownerid).Name + ' on ' + System.now().format('M/d/yyyy K:mm:ss a','America/Chicago') + '.' + '\r\n' + t.description;
                        }
                        t.ownerid = cMap.get(t.whoid).ownerid;
                        UpdatedTasks.add(t);
                    }
                }
                
                //Update Tasks in the database.
                if (!updatedTasks.isempty()) {
                    Update updatedTasks;
                }
            }
            
            for (Contact c : cList) {
                c.contact_owner_updated__c = false;
            }
            
            update cList;
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```java
@isTest
public class TestDailyTaskOwnerUpdateScheduledClass {
    
    //Removing current tests as the curren DailyTaskOwnerUpdate is being replaced entirely with the batch process.
    
    /*
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';
    
    static testmethod void test1() {
        Contact c = new Contact( FirstName = 'TestD4651', LastName = 'Test', targetx_srmb__status__c = 'Inquiry', ownerid = '00515000006yYHKAA2', targetx_srmb__campus__c = 'Online Education', contact_owner_updated__c = true );
        insert c;
        Task t = new Task( whoid = c.id, ownerid = '00515000006eTLy', Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk', status = 'Not Started', Description = '' );
        Task t2 = new Task( whoid = c.id, ownerid = '00515000006eTLy', Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk2', status = 'Not Started', Description = 'Testing Description');
        List<Task> tList = New List<Task>();
        tList.add(t);
        tList.add(t2);
        insert tList;
        
        Test.startTest();
        String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest',
                                       CRON_EXP, 
                                       new DailyTaskOwnerUpdate());
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, 
                            ct.CronExpression);
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
        System.assertEquals('2022-03-15 00:00:00', 
                            String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));
        Test.stopTest();
        
        c = [SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, ownerid FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'TestD4651' LIMIT 1];
        tList = [SELECT ID, ownerid FROM Task WHERE Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk' OR Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk2' ];
        System.assert(tList[0].ownerid == c.ownerid);
        System.assert(tList[1].ownerid == c.ownerid);
    }
    
    static testmethod void test2() {
        List<Contact> cList = new List<Contact>();
        for (integer i = 0; i >= 100; i++ ) {
            Contact c = new Contact( FirstName = 'TestD4651' + i, LastName = 'Test', targetx_srmb__status__c = 'Inquiry', ownerid = '00515000006yYHKAA2', targetx_srmb__campus__c = 'Online Education', contact_owner_updated__c = true );
          cList.add(c);
        }
        
        insert cList;
        
        cList = [SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, ownerid FROM Contact WHERE FirstName LIKE 'TestD4651%'];
        
        List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
        
        for (Contact c : cList) {
            Task t = new Task( whoid = c.id, ownerid = '00515000006eTLy', Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk', status = 'Not Started', Description = '' );
            tList.add(t);
        }
        
        insert tList;
        
        Test.startTest();
        String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest',
                                       CRON_EXP, 
                                       new DailyTaskOwnerUpdate());
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                          FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, 
                            ct.CronExpression);
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);
        System.assertEquals('2022-03-15 00:00:00', 
                            String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));
        Test.stopTest();
        
        tList = [SELECT ID, ownerid FROM Task WHERE Subject = 'TestingUHD87y6JKbs&sbk'];
        
        Map<ID,Contact> cMap = new Map<ID,Contact>();
        cMap.putAll(cList);
        
        boolean tResult = true;
        for (Task t : tList) {
            if (t.ownerid != cMap.get(t.whoid).ownerid) {
                tResult = false;
            }
        }
        
        System.assert(tResult);
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: The issue here is `ForgotPasswordController`, which seems to expect that the class you've posted implements the `Batchable` interface and not the `Schedulable` interface. If you're changing `DailyTaskOwnerBatchUpdate` like this, then you also need to update (and deploy) everything else that uses it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the same error message on every other Apex Class, not just the ForgotPassword Controller. That's just the example I used. Would it make more sense to change DailyTaskOwnerBatchUpdate to Batchable instead of Schedulable? Is that possible?